# Json decode isnt working

Tags: php, html, json, steam

This is the part who does errors:

```
$inv = 'http://steamapi.csgodirect.com/getInventory?steamid=76561198076372985';
@$inv = file_get_contents($inv);
$inv = json_decode($inv, true);
if($inv['success'] != 1) {
        $privateinventory = 1;
}
 else{
       $privateinventory = 0;

       }

echo $privateinventory;
```

I always get 1, but it should be 0.
JSON - Code is avaiable on the Site but for some reason he says it was not successfull.

Comment: There is no success key in the given json..

Comment: You should _always_ check your error log, and turn on _display_errors_ while developing in your local environment. Then you would see that @MASIDDIQUI is correct... there's no `success`-field in the json.

Comment: but it is working for an other guy on his server..

Comment: Well we can only point out the facts, there is no success key in this specific JSON output. I suspect your API query is incorrect. See for yourself by browsing to the url `http://steamapi.csgodirect.com/getInventory?steamid=76561198076372985` and then using `ctrl-f` and attempt  to find `success`.

Comment: Maybe the other guy passing 'success' key with the json.

Comment: @Zoetrope Try with this url you found 
    http://steamapi.csgodirect.com/getInventory?steamid=76561198%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B076372985  
 success key that gave this output {"success":false}

Comment: @Zoetrope: There is no success key within the JSON. Also are you sure you are using same code as that other guy is having

Comment: If it works for someone else or not is irrelevant, since we don't have that code and can see how that guy does what, where and why. Now you, at least, know why your code is failing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no success key in given json file but if you need to check you can check if json is valid or not with json_decode($inv) != null , for now from your question i thought this may help you.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$inv = 'http://steamapi.csgodirect.com/getInventory?steamid=76561198076372985';
@$inv = file_get_contents($inv);
//var_dump($inv);

//var_dump(json_decode($inv, true));

if (json_decode($inv) != null) {
    $privateinventory = 0;
} else {
    $privateinventory = 1;
}

echo $privateinventory;
```

If this will not match your requirements then try to describe more.

Comment: You should ask if that is enough in a comment before assuming it in an answer.

Comment: No idea what you mean by that, I'm just pointing out that it's better to ask for more info in comments before you write an answer, since a spot on answer is better for the OP than assumptions. Btw, I'm not the downvoter...

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am new here and you down-vote my answer its kind of odd. hope you can understand

Comment: Like I said, I'm not the downvoter. However, I did give you a reason for why someone might.